# How to explain the feeling in the plane?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Why I can't feel the actual speed of plane when the plane in the sky? I mean I cannot judge how fast the plane is going in terms of the light on the ground and I feel it is flying so slow. How can I explain this mismatch?

Comment: You are moving at the speed of the plane, in the same frame of reference. Objects on the ground are far enough away that we don't have a familiar reference. Objects no longer provide a distance scale. So when in a plane, cars appear slower but they are actually moving at a normal car speed. Can you judge the speed of a plane easily from the ground? It is not so easy with no reference. Airplanes use instruments such as pitot tubes, which measure the flow speed of air passing through them, to determine air speed.

Comment: You have no point of reference. If you are flying at high altitude, and you see an another aircraft below you, heading  in the opposite direction, you will get a better idea of the speed you are really moving at. When you are on approach to land, just before you touchdown touchdown.you will get another point of reference to judge your speed by. Its the same for pilots, if they don't trust their instruments, they will often misjudge their speed.

Comment: Another anologue is the fact that we are moving around the sun at high velocity. Is it easy to judge the speed at which were moving through space as a planet?

Comment: You have spent most of your life estimating speeds using objects that are close to you. In a commercial passenger plane, the "nearest object" is the ground which is several miles away from you.  When you are a passenger in a car, try estimating the speed by only looking at objects on the horizon. (Look out of the side window, and block off everything except a narrow strip at the top of the window, so you can't see things close to the road.) You will get exactly the same effect as when you are in a plane.

Answer (score 1):

You do not feel speed, you only feel acceleration, or other forces, like those from the wind on your face - and you cannot feel that in a plane.

So you do feel something when the plane is accelerating, taking off, sometimes when it banks, or in bad weather.

But a plane's speed is typically steady, unchanging, for most of the trip.

When changes in the plane's motion occur they are relatively small (except for very bad weather, jet stream turbulence and the like ).  The plane's motion is normally kept within reasonable acceleration rates for the precise reason to avoid passenger discomfort (and to avoid excessive stress on the airframe).

So you're in a system that's designed to minimize your sensation of motion.

As you're high up, you cannot see how fast the plane's ground speed is.  The closer you are to a passing object, the faster you think you're going.  You're not close to the ground so it almost drifts by.

A similar effect is why some people experience more fear when driving that others.  They concentrate on the road surface near their car and it gives a greater impression of speed than the place they should be looking (further ahead).  You might also notice it if you were on a skateboard and compared the sensation of speed when standing to that when kneeling.

The speed doesn't change, but your brain picks up different clues to motion and interprets them as different speeds.  In a high flying plane there are no obvious speed clues so your brain can interpret that as not moving fast.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's an illusion that has to do more with cognitive science. The treatment of objects movements and the evaluation of their speed is done pretty unconsciously through different visual areas of the cortex. [Some people for example cannot perceive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akinetopsia) motion even though they see perfectly well! This information is also completed by other sources of information that help us "feel" the speed like feeling the wind,  vibrations, noise and eye movements.  
So the feel of speed is not a rational process! Most likely it was developed to help us hunt or escape the attack of an animal.  But not to judge the speed of an aircraft. 
Then somehow all this information reaches [Speed cells](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2015/07/speed-cells-brain-track-how-fast-animals-run) that among  Place cells, Grid cells, Boundary cell and Head direction cells form the "human GPS system". When in a plane, all the information reaching the speed cells is biased and thinking rationally about our real speed can't really change the slow "feel" of our speed cells. Maybe a lot of training could help. One should ask test or fighter pilots if they feel the real speed.

 People who vote your question down should get [a life.](https://www.cheaptickets.com/)

Comment: From my family background, I can say that even pilots of 30 years can be caught out by thinking they can judge speeds by their senses. They are told repeatedly to 1.  trust their instruments, and 2.  check the pitot tubes. In the simulators, the instruments are regularly switched off and the pilots then just as regularly get disoriented.